# Getting job key from job class name in Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to delete a job for which I need job key. I only know the job class name. Please suggest how to get the same using job class name.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this information if you iterate over all jobgroups of your scheduler instances. From there you get the jobKey. With the jobKey you can ask for the jobDetail, which holds the class information. If it matches just return the key.

```
public JobKey getJobKeyByJobClass (Scheduler scheduler, String className){  
    for (final String group : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
        for (final JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher.groupEquals(group))) {
            if(className.equals(scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey).getJobClass().getName())){
                return jobKey;
            }                               
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I know job group name. But the problem is I want to avoid overhead of iterating over jobs as number of jobs is very high.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid iterating? Do you have millions of jobs, or do you need to execute this search 1000 times per seconds? I think for your case it is no problem at all. If you are not sure just messure the execution time ;)

Comment: My application can have any number of jobs. So, I can't iterate. However, my job is already running in my application. I just have to stop it manually at some point and all I have is class name of the job.

Comment: Far as i know you can't just kill a "running" job because the job is executed in a thread from the scheduler thread pool. If your job does not implement some own kill logic it will be run until the execution determines.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain `JobKey` by several ways. Let's imagine that your `Job` implemenation is `MyJob` class.

1. From `JobExecutionContext`. If your job is executing you can

   ```
   Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler(); 
   JobKey jobKey = null;
   for (JobExecutionContext jobCtx : scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()) {
       JobDetail jobDetail = jobCtx.getJobDetail();
       if (MyJob.class.equals(jobDetail.getJobClass())) {
           jobKey = jobDetail.getKey();
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   same with streams

   ```
   Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler(); 
   Optional<JobDetail> job = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()
                 .stream()
                 .map(JobExecutionContext::getJobDetail)
                 .filter(jobDetail -> MyJob.class.equals(jobDetail.getJobClass()))
                 .findFirst();
   JobKey jobKey = job.isPresent() ? job.get().getKey() : null;
   ```
2. By group name. Ususally, when you're submitting new job for execution you're providing group and job names. If you're not doing so, start, it will make the things easier:)

   ```
   Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
   JobKey jobKey = null;
   for (JobKey jk : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals("myGroup"))) {
       if (MyJob.class.equals(scheduler.getJobDetail(jk).getJobClass())) {
           jobKey = jk;
           break; 
       }
   }
   ```

   same with streams

   ```
   Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler(); 
   Optional<JobDetail> job = scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals("myGroup"))
                 .stream()
                 .map(jk -> scheduler.getJobDetail(jk))
                 .filter(jobDetail -> MyJob.class.equals(jobDetail.getJobClass()))
                 .findFirst();
   JobKey jobKey = job.isPresent() ? job.get().getKey() : null;
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there a way to avoid iteration. My job is already running in my application and I am trying to find out a way to stop it manually at some point of time.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma, it's easy, just create group with single job you want to terminate. Everything else is the same, you're querying `scheduler` for JobKeys by your group and there will be only target job. :)
Do you want to terminate Job from its implementation class?

Comment: Yes I also thought doing it by creating single group. Yes, I want to terminate Job from its implementation class.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma, then you probably have access to `JobExecutionContext`. Getting key is obvious in this case `jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey()`.

Comment: Slight change. I want to create an api which will access my implementation class using GUICE. I was thinking to store value of key into some variable in implementation class and then use it in the rest endpoint to play with the job.